# Xcode simulator just show a quarter desktop

Tags: xcode

I create a simple single-view application project, then run it. The simulator shows a quarter desktop. so strange, I want to see a full-screen result.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting command 1. Or if that doesn't work then see if in the main file (very top of navigation bar) if the box is checked where it says something like *require fullscreen* or *show in fullscreen*